# Iniciar proyecto con carpeta zip de ionic creator

Tags: ionic2

Realicé un proyecto en `Ionic creator` y lo exporté en `zip`, este archivo contiene la carpeta `src`.

Luego descargué una plantilla `blank` desde la consola pero ahora no sé donde debo poner la carpeta `src` en la plantilla `blank`, en la raíz o dentro de `www`?

[image: Estructura de la plantilla blank]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el problema... en el comando de instalación me faltaba poner --v2. El comando completo debe ser `ionic start MyApp blank --v2`